# Conflict with Dotdigitalgroup and Magento\Email\Model\Template\SenderResolver / Magento2

Tags: magento2, conflict

So we installed a fresh `M2.3.5`

and are seeing a conflict between these 2:

```
Magento\Email\Model\Template\SenderResolver
Dotdigitalgroup\Email\Model\Email\DotdigitalSenderResolver
```

Now we have never installed anything from Dotdigitalgroup.

**Question**: what is the fastest way of finding out to what extension or source the code from `Dotdigitalgroup` comes from?

Comment: How does this conflict look? Is there an error? We are just setting a preference in DI in order to use custom template code in an email send: https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/blob/master/etc/di.xml#L110. Keen to know if we can reduce friction here.

Answer (score 1):

[Dotdigitalgroup modules](https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension) installed by default with the Magento 2 instance.

Installed directory : `magento/vendor/dotmailer`

Three modules relate to dotdigital as follows which you can disable

`Dotdigitalgroup_Email`

`Dotdigitalgroup_Chat`

`Dotdigitalgroup_Enterprise`

Below module disable command will surely help you

`php bin/magento module:disable --clear-static-content Dotdigitalgroup_Email Dotdigitalgroup_Chat Dotdigitalgroup_Enterprise`

Comment: Interesting then that there is a DEFAULT conflict ... feels very silly

Comment: What does DotDigital do?

Comment: I only needed to disable php bin/magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Chat

Answer (score 1):

I recommend removing via composer

https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-all/blob/50355d3133c42ec025e289a3421854f2737af7e5/composer.json#L14-L17

```
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-enterprise": "*",
        "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package": "*",
```

Dotmailer is email marketing

Also if third party you can use composer command to find out what's brought it in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59975169/10121426

Use `composer` `depends` with the `--tree` option.

Example: say I want to see a tree structure of what packages depend on the `doctrine/data-fixtures` package up to the `_root_` package.

```
composer depends --tree doctrine/data-fixtures
```

Output:

```
doctrine/data-fixtures 1.4.0 Data Fixtures for all Doctrine Object Managers
└──doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.3.0 (requires doctrine/data-fixtures ^1.3)
   └──__root__ (requires (for development) doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle ^3.3)
```

Another argument is `why`

Example:

```
composer why nyholm/psr7
```

Output:

```
justbetter/magento2-sentry  2.2.3  requires  nyholm/psr7 (^1.2)
```

Full Example on one of the components above:

```
composer why dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat
dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package  4.4.0  requires  dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat (1.0.1)  

composer why dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package
magento/product-community-edition  2.3.5-p1  requires  dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package (4.4.0) 

composer depends --tree dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat
dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat 1.0.1 Engagement Cloud for Magento 2: Chat module
└──dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package 4.4.0 (requires dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat 1.0.1)
   └──magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 (requires dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package 4.4.0)
      └──magento/project-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 (requires magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1)
```

Comment: After doing his we still needed to disable somehow? or maybe disable before update, after remove?